LXQt task bar position with second screen (Lubuntu 24.04)
I'd like to put my second panel on the laptops screen to the bottom. But the dialog only allows me to put it on the second monitor on the left at the bottom - but I already have a secondary bar on that monitor.
The combobox only offers 4 possible locations: top, bottom, left, right and assigns them at random to the two available screens.

Strangely the maximized terminal shows, that the window-manager reserves both the space to the right under the laptops taskbar AND at the bottom of the screen (that's because of the second panel on the left monitor).
It seems, maximized Windows are reaching into the adjacent screen, because they also appear in the other screens task-bar, though it filters them correctly once they are non-maximized windows with some security margin away from the second screen.
My question: Where does the dialog store its settings? Maybe a clear-file, that I can fiddle with in an editor?
PS: My panel looks completely overhauled since 2020
PPS: Versions:
LXQt 1.4
Lubuntu 24.04 noble
Kernel 6.8.0-38-generic

You mention Lubuntu which hasn't used LXDE since 18.04; and also LXDE rather significantly; have you switched desktops on your system? or how does LXDE relate?  (LXDE and LXQt panels are different programs)

The LXQt panel config on a Lubuntu system can be found at ~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf along with a lot of other LXQt config files.
guiverc@d7050-next:~/.config/lxqt$   stat ~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf 
  File: /home/guiverc/.config/lxqt/panel.conf
  Size: 19940       Blocks: 40         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 8,6 Inode: 1709349     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ guiverc)   Gid: ( 1000/ guiverc)
Access: 2024-07-20 08:32:21.984179670 +1000
Modify: 2024-07-12 12:06:16.170489637 +1000
Change: 2024-07-12 12:06:16.174489636 +1000
 Birth: 2024-07-12 12:06:16.170489637 +1000


You are right, it is LXQt ... corrected.
Also reading the files in ~/.config/lxqt was helpfull. It seems, the virtual space allocated to the monitors was overlapping by one pixel - so as screenshot of full width resulted in an image of widthTotal=widthA+widthB-1.
I fixed it by moving the virtual screens on top of each other and then back next to each other, so they snapped in place. Now the screen-Layout is pixel-perfect and allows for 6 toolbars (just not in between the screens). Also maximized windows don't leak to the second screen anymore.
